# python for loop to read csv files from a list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, append

I want to read csv files in a `for` loop using `pandas`. I have put the names of the files in a list. After each iteration each file has to be appended to `result`. Using the folowing code I can only append one file:

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['fileA.csv' , 'fileB.csv']
result = None

for files in files: 
    df1 = pd.read_csv(files)
    df1['JourneyID'] = 'Journey2'
    df1.set_index( 'JourneyID', inplace=True)
    df1b = df1.head(15)
    if result is None:
       result = df1b
    else:
        result.append(df1b)

 result.head(30)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure above code is correctly indented? It looks like your `if/else` should be inside the for loop

Comment: It is inside the for loop, you re right - typo mistake

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: They are files that they have info about the journey, eg vehicle, weather conditions, time of the journey. The files have the same columns name and format. If I dont use for loop then it works. It seems that it doesnt do the append correclty. I m not quite sure if the if/else statement together with the result is None is being used correclty

Comment: `df.append` returns a *new* DataFrame - it doesn't update the frame inplace... It's not ideal as you probably want to handle this a different way (depending on what you need/constraints), but you can use `result = result.append(df1b)` in the `else`... to bind `result` to be the actual new dataframe so it keeps the previous and new elements each loop...

Comment: Yes, that is it. it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is in your use of the `.append()` method. `result` is a `DataFrame` for which the `append` method behaves differently than for let's say a python list.
Whereas the `.append()` for a python list appends the object in place, the `DataFrame.append()` method returns a new object. So you need to write

```
result = result.append(df1b)
```

For further Info, refer to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

> DataFrame.append(other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False)
>   Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.

Comment: yes it worked. I want to ask one more please. Every file should ideally have different index value, eg file1 should have as index value Journey1, and file2 should have Journey2. Does python have this kind of thing? Like macros?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, then you can achieve this by using `for i,file in enumerate(files)` at the top of your for loop and then `df1['JourneyID'] = 'Journey' + str(i)`

Comment: yes exactly this is what I was asking. I need to find it because I m getting weird results but thanks a lot!